# How to Convert Null Value in 0 using pivot Sql Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my query I am doing to show the report card of a daily basis work by field executive. All record are correct but I want to display a date in header or fill null value with 0.

```
[DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max); 
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);SELECT @Pivot_Column= COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ 
QUOTENAME([DAY])  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT datepart(day,statusupdatedate) as [Day] 
FROM tbl_trn_RawData where StatusUpdateDate is not null and DATENAME(MONTH,StatusUpdateDate)='July') 
 Tab SELECT @Query='SELECT [FE Name], '+@Pivot_Column+'FROM(select [FE name],count(StatusByFE) as [Total],
  datepart(day,statusupdatedate) as [Day] FROM tbl_trn_RawData where StatusUpdateDate is not null  group by
   [FE name],statusupdatedate) Tab1 PIVOT(SUM([Total]) FOR [Day] IN ('+@Pivot_Column+')) AS Day ORDER BY Day.
   [FE name]'EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```

My result is coming like this:

[image: This is my result review please tell me where i need to correct]

Comment: I need urgent help pls help me

Comment: `isnull(columnName,0)`

Comment: could you please tell me where i add this

Comment: What ever column returns null which is all of them almost

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
create table tbl_trn_RawData([FE name] varchar(50),StatusUpdateDate date, StatusByFE int)
go
insert into  tbl_trn_RawData
values ('Ananesh Raghav','2018-07-12',3),
('Ananesh Raghav','2018-07-14',5),
('Lokendra Raghav','2018-07-14',1),
('Narinder Singh','2018-07-12',2),
('Narinder Singh','2018-07-13',5)
go
DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max); 
DECLARE @Pivot_ColumnNotNull [nvarchar](max); 
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);
SELECT @Pivot_Column= COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ QUOTENAME([DAY]),
       @Pivot_ColumnNotNull= COALESCE(@Pivot_ColumnNotNull+',','')+ QUOTENAME([DAY])+'=coalesce('+QUOTENAME([DAY])+',0)'  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT datepart(day,statusupdatedate) as [Day] 
FROM tbl_trn_RawData 
where StatusUpdateDate is not null 
and DATENAME(MONTH,StatusUpdateDate)='July') 
 Tab 

 SELECT @Query='
 ;with p as (
    SELECT top 100 percent [FE Name], '+@Pivot_Column+
    'FROM(select [FE name],count(StatusByFE) as [Total],
            datepart(day,statusupdatedate) as [Day] 
            FROM tbl_trn_RawData where StatusUpdateDate is not null  
            group by [FE name],statusupdatedate) Tab1 
    PIVOT(SUM([Total]) 
    FOR [Day] IN ('+@Pivot_Column+')) AS Day 
    ORDER BY Day.[FE name]
  ) 
  SELECT [FE Name], '+@Pivot_ColumnNotNull+' FROM p'EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```